# If K is a perfect field, is any extension of K also a Galois Extension?

Tags: galois-theory

So I have got that if K is a perfect field then every irreducible polynomial over K is separable. (Separable meaning it has no repeated roots). 
Is it then possible to conclude that every finite extension of K is separable and every algebraic extension of K is separable? 
Hence the statement is true?

Comment: Galois requires separable and normal.

Comment: A galois extension is supposed to be also normal.

Comment: It’s certainly true that any algebraic extension of a perfect field is perfect.